# Is there an alternative way of serializing javascript objects to a json string?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I downloaded the code from json.org to serialize/deserialize javascript objects to/from json and it worked just fine. However, in production, it conflicts with my other javascript code apparently because it uses `for` in loops. Is there another library that does this? Thanks!

Comment: How does using for conflict with your code?

Comment: Yeah, I want to know the answer to that, too. You must have some code that adds junk to native objects? Nasty.

Comment: I think Nosredna nailed it.  It sounds like you might be modifying the Object.prototype object...  Big bad voodoo.

Answer (score 2):

I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), specifically with the [jQuery-JSON plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/).  As you can see from the link, this works like so

```
var thing = {plugin: 'jquery-json', version: 1.3};
var encoded = $.toJSON(thing);              //'{"plugin": "jquery-json", "version": 1.3}'
var name = $.evalJSON(encoded).plugin;      //"jquery-json"
var version = $.evalJSON(encoded).version;  // 1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [YUI JSON utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/)?